# Compare values with previous values and count the change : Pandas Groupby

Tags: python, pandas

I have a panadas dataframe shown below :

```
masterid    price
1001        12
1001        12
1001        11
1001        14
1002        15
1003        10
1003        10
1003        10
1004        16
1004        17
```

I want to count the times when the price changes for a particular master id

Example : For masterid 1001 the price changed from 12 - 11 and from 11 -14 ( 2 times )

Expected output :

```
masterid    price
1001        2
1002        0
1003        0
1004        1
```

I have tried using `(df['price'].ne(df['price'].shift())` but not sure how to use group by in this case. Thanks in advance

Comment: posted an answer, is that what you were looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there. The next step is to use `pd.groupby.apply` with your existing function and sum:

```
df.groupby('masterid').apply(
    lambda df: (df['price'].ne(df['price'].shift())
).sum())
```

This stragegy should work pretty generally, though in some cases `apply` will be slow.

Answer (score 1):

```
#calculate the price difference using diff
# take absolute value and compare with zero
# go another group by and take the count

df.assign(price=
          df.groupby('masterid')['price']
          .diff()
          .abs()>0)
.groupby(['masterid'])['price']
.sum()
.reset_index()
```

```
masterid    price
0   1001    2
1   1002    0
2   1003    0
3   1004    1
```

Comment: Thanks @Naveed. Great logic using absolute value with difference.

Comment: Glad it worked for you. Consider accepting the answer that worked for you. @Ash